# Error message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')"

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to learning react and have been having problems getting the array to filter using the .filter() method. I'm trying to create a grocery list and I keep getting the error message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')" Can someone please assist me on getting this work? Here is the code that I have.

```
import Header from './Header';
import SearchItem from './SearchItem';
import AddItem from './AddItem';
import Content from './Content';
import Footer from './Footer';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppinglist')));
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState('')
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

  console.log('before useEffect')

  //useEffect looks to it's dependency and if the dependency changes then it will run the anonymous function
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('inside useEffect')
  },[items])

  const setAndSaveItems = (newItems) => {
    setItems(newItems);
    localStorage.setItem('shoppinglist', JSON.stringify(newItems));
  }

  console.log('after useEffect')

  const addItem = (item) => {
    const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;
    const myNewItem = { id, checked: false, item };
    const listItems = [...items, myNewItem];
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleCheck = (id) => {
    const listItems = items.map((item) => item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item);
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const listItems = items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!newItem) return;
    addItem(newItem);
    setNewItem('');
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="Grocery List" />
      <AddItem
        newItem={newItem}
        setNewItem={setNewItem}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
      <SearchItem
        search={search}
        setSearch={setSearch}
      />
      <Content
        items={items.filter(item => ((item.item).toLowerCase()).includes(search.toLowerCase()))}
        handleCheck={handleCheck}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
      />
      <Footer length={items.length} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers that could help

initilize the items in an useEffect as it could be null, it will make it easy to fetch data a api later

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

  try {

     const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppinglist'))
     setItems(items) 

  } catch(error) {

  }

}, [])

  // put ?. checks on items when calling filter, map
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const listItems = items?.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    if (listItems) {
       setAndSaveItems(listItems);
    }
  }
```

Id generated will clash and cause bugs

```
const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;
```

if the person deletes on item and adds another the new item will have the same id as the last one

- item { id: 1}
- item { id: 2}
- item { id: 3}

after deleting id 2, when you add new items it will have id 3
and will cause bugs with select

either use a id that is a timestamp or check for unique ids

- Save the items in local storage on submit, as calls get/set items to localstorage can lead to performace issues in the UI

Checkout the new docs on [working with arrays](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you're mentioning about this code excerpt:

> items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);

can you please check if the **items** array is null or not. Only if **items** is null, filtering wouldn't be applicable and you will receive such error messages

can you log **items** before deletion?